# UXTheme dll symbols and AccentColor

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I was trying to get Accent Color for use in my WPF app, and i found one class in GitHub that always is the same.

```
static class UxTheme
    {
        [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "#98", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern uint GetImmersiveUserColorSetPreference(bool forceCheckRegistry, bool skipCheckOnFail);

        [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "#94", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern uint GetImmersiveColorSetCount();

        [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "#95", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern uint GetImmersiveColorFromColorSetEx(uint immersiveColorSet, uint immersiveColorType,
            bool ignoreHighContrast, uint highContrastCacheMode);

        [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "#96", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern uint GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName(IntPtr name);

        [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "#100", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetImmersiveColorNamedTypeByIndex(uint index);
}
```

I was finding uxtheme documentation in SDK and MSDN but this methods aren't.

I dumpbin uxtheme.dll and surprise! they are unnamed functions. (Except #95 & #98).

How can i get signatures of the uxtheme (or others) library? Then, i can try-error guessing the functions i need.

Comment: These are undocumented functions. Subject to change at any time. Reverse engineering is all you can do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how can i do it? Some app? Some way?

Comment: Use dumpbin and your debugger